# Galeria de light-Box

Tags: javascript, jquery

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: deseo poner unas imágenes diseñadas en phothoshop como imágenes de muestra en mi pagina, estan recortadas en forma de rombo, pero quiero que al darle click me muestre otra imagen, que tengo dentro de otra carpeta de imágenes... me explico.

Tengo la imagen X que está en `src="img/x.png"...`
pero quiero que al darle click me muestre la imagen Y ... que esta en otra carpeta distinta....

De como hacerlo con js, pero no quiero repetir el codigo, **¿cómo lo hago de manera eficiente?**... el código que estoy usando es este

```
$('.img').click(function(e){
    var modal = '<div class="modal" id="modal"><img src="img/section2/mst/Asset8.jpg" class="modal-img"><div class="modal-btn" id="modal-btn">X</div></div>';
    $('body').append(modal);
    $('#modal-btn').click(function(){
        $('#modal').remove();
    });
});
```

Pero son 12 imágenes, no quiero repetir este código 12 veces para cada imagen, **¿cómo hago un solo código en `jquery` para las 12 imágenes?**

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que haría es que las dos formas:

- Si quieres usar dos carpetas haría que las dos imágenes (en ambas carpetas) se llamasen igual. Entonces es tan sencillo como, cuando haces click, reemplazar una carpeta por otra y listo.
- Lo mismo te es más fácil mantener las imágenes en una sola carpeta e identificarlas por un sufijo (por ejemplo, "_diamond" y "_square") y así, igual que en el caso anterior, es cambiar un sufijo por otro.

En mi opinión creo que es más fácil el segundo método porque es más fácil de gestionar si tienes las imágenes juntas y el reemplazo también es algo más fácil ya que todas las imágenes están en la misma carpeta.